# Can I unsubscribe from email chains in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

At the job where I work I am often the recipient of emails that have been addressed to the entire building. These emails are OK, but unfortunately most of the other people who receive them don't seem to know the difference between 'Reply' and 'Reply to all', and I will wind up receiving many response emails that I have no interest in getting.

Is there any way that I can unsubscribe from these email chains and save myself from being buried by multiple "me too" emails?

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2007 on Exchange (unknown version, run by corporate).

Comment: No. Other then asking the initial sender to always send group emails to the BCC field,  thus making it impossible to reply to all.

Comment: @Xantec - Nope.  In either the case mailing list is the recipient or you are a specific recipient being emailed you can't be removed from these emails.

Comment: Most unfortunate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just click the 'Ignore' button...it will auto-delete the thread and any future messages that come in on the same thread. Very quick and efficient for group emails you don't care about.

[image: outlook ignore button]

Comment: Sounds great. I'll check for it tomorrow.

Comment: Odd, the version of Outlook 2007 my employer uses doesn't have the ribbon interface in the main app window, although child windows (for emails, tasks, meetings etc) all have it. I can't seem to locate any method to active the Ignore feature in the standard menu bar or the email window either. But as Microsoft's sites confirm it should exist in 2007, your answer is accepted.

Comment: Hmm, this may have been a new feature in 2010, i'm just so used to it, I thought it was old.  Sorry if you haven't been able to find it, maybe there is an add on that replicates the functionality?

Answer (score 6):

I'm a little late to the Outlook party, but I found the following workaround which would allow one to achieve this:

- Select ***Reply All*** (and mention that you're removing yourself from the thread).
- Go to the ***Options*** tab.
- Select ***Direct Replies To*** and specify that replies are to be directed to some other user who is currently in the conversation.

Now, all further ***Reply All***-s will have you removed from the recipient list (unless explicitly re-added, of course).

**P.S.:** This is only when you were initially mentioned explicitly as a recepient. This will not work if you're part of a list present in the recipient field.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a rule that looks for the "all employees" group (I am assuming that its mailing a group) and the `RE:` in the subject line.  That would cover all replies to the original message. However, you run the risk of potentially missing something important.

another possibility would be if you are using an "All Employees" distribution group, the Exchange admins can restrict who can mail to that group.

Answer (score 0):

Open the address book and scroll down until you see your group. If it is in bold font, then you are able to take yourself out of it. Just double click and you will see “Members”. Click on yourself and then click “modify members”. You will then see the option to click on yourself again and then click remove. It’s pretty self-explanatory once you realize you have to go into the address book.