# Replying to email chain without being reply all-able

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, reply

I've become part of a large email thread that I no longer need to be part of. Is it possible to reply to all of them while removing myself from the list, such that when they reply all on the latest email I'm not part of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://superuser.com/questions/603308/can-i-unsubscribe-from-email-chains-in-outlook

Comment: @New-To-IT I dont want to ignore future mailings (in case I get pulled back in) and I dont want to delete old ones. That answer does not suit me.

Comment: It will still be there for you in the deleted items folder, you just have to un-ignore the thread.

Comment: You can have the admin create a special group that the sender sends to. This list will have to be maintained by the sender. Sometimes email is not the best tool when all you want is the ability to subscribe to a thread... It is, unfortunately, the common platform that everyone knows. Same issue with people using Excel as a database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things after **Reply to All**:-

1. Remove your own address from the **To** list.
2. Change your **Reply to** address to something like **NoReply@...**.

If you specify a valid e-mail address which you choose to ignore, you will continue to receive e-mails on it. If you specify a non-existent address the senders will get non-delivery notices and eventually they will remove you, but you will get nothing while this is going on.

Depending on the nature of the e-mails, and whether or not the subject will change, you may or may not be able to identify which e-mails belong to those you want to ignore.

The only other possibility is to ask someone else on the list to remove you on their next broadcast.

Comment: How do I change my Reply To address?

Comment: You will have to change it in your account settings. You can change the From address at the same time. Don't forget to change them back after you have sent the e-mail.

Comment: @David Grinberg Go to the Options tab. Update Direct Replies To. Applies to just the one message.